# How does Discord get infinite Spotify tokens without new authorization?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, spotify

I'm trying to make a Spotify application (interfacing the API using Python 3.8 and the `requests` module). From what I understand, this is how the Authorization Code flow works:

1. User clicks Authorize/Agree, gets redirected to specified URL (ex. https://john.doe/redirect?code=ABC&state=XYZ)
2. I store the `code` and `state` variables in a database for later use.
3. When I want a Spotify token, I make a proper API request and specify the previously mentioned `code` parameter.
4. That token expires after an hour so if I need another one I can use the `refresh_token` for another token.

The problem is that I can only get 2 tokens before the user needs to revisit the authorization page. I noticed Discord doesn't have this issue whatsoever. You grant Discord access to your Spotify token and never have to see that authorization page again. How come Discord doesn't have to reauthorize? Or if they *do*, how are they doing it discreetly?

I found this question that seems similar: [How does Discord connect to third party APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587360/how-does-discord-connect-to-third-party-apis) but this has gone unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

As your point 4 says, each time you request access token you get refresh_token.

After your access token expires you request another one using the refresh token.
As a response from this you'll get NEW access token AND new refresh token (that you can use to request new pair of access token & refresh token)

Feel free reading more here https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

You can also read more about refreshing access token for Spotify in Python at Spotipy's docs
https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/?highlight=refresh#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth.refresh_access_token

Comment: Reusing the `code` variable seems to work, how interesting. Thank you!

Comment: I can't get this to work. I get the following response: `{"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Authorization code expired"}` ??